# Relative height and width but absolute positioned x, y

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a huge horizontal scrolling website. Think of a [Mario World](http://gamesbackgrounds.com/walls/super_mario_world_wallpaper_4-HD.jpg), as an example. Every "asset" is positioned absolute.

I would like to have the size (height and width) of the items to be relative to the browser's viewport (so using percentages) but need to position the items using actual pixels from the left etc.

When I do this, obviously, the assets are correctly resized as I resize my browser window. But the positions of the items are in pixels, so things move out of place in relation to the background.

Is there a simple CSS solution to this problem? Using percentages to define the position (left: 50% for example) is not really a good solution since it's not very accurate (see jsfiddle below). Or should I look at the resize event using JS and do something that way? If so, how?

I'm not sure if I'm making sense right now.. so let me know if there are any questions.

**Edit**

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BZ77t/

Note that when you resize the window, the black block (`#blockpx`) is positioned using pixels and therefor not affected during resizing. The red block (`#blockpercentage`), however, is sized and positioned using percentages, achieving the effect I want: sticking to the intended position (which is the position of the background image). However, it's not really accurate – which does not matter that much in this example, but in a bigger setting (wider width), the difference gets quite high.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @starowere, just updated my question with a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a combination of a containing element and javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/KaaXg/3/

This fiddle includes this javascript functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".container").css("width", $(".image").width());        
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $(".container").css("width", $(".image").width());        
    });
});
```

The most important thing to note here is that `left` and `width` values were being calculated with respect to the `body` element, which was unintended.

To counter this, we've added a containing element which contains the image and other `div` tags used for the red block graphics on the page.

However, without javascript, the `left` attribute still only "updates" when the page is reloaded after the window has been resized. Block level elements do not update horizontally on their own.

So you want the `left` and `width` to be proportional to the background image, but they won't update as the page is resized or moved around using only CSS. The javascript solution above updates the width of the containing element dynamically as the page is resized, solving this problem.

I left the `bottom` and `height` css styles alone, since they work as intended for the purposes of your website, the container grows in height to accomodate the image within it.

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with the fixed-pixel black block on the page, so I left it as-is.

***EDIT: I seriously overhauled this project, made an object factory to create new graphics and updated the code for the page. This solution requires almost no HTML or CSS, has a bit more javascript code, but will make it much easier to implement dynamic graphics on the page/functional addition of new elements. http://jsfiddle.net/RnCWN/9/***

The javascript solution I came up here with uses real-time updating percentages to set the `width` and `left` attributes of the percentage based block, as well as initializing the static `height` and `bottom` attributes.

With this revision, you can use the method `PercentageBasedGraphic` to create a floating box on your page. Here's an example:

```
PercentageBasedGraphic(25, 10, 4, 30, "block1");
```

This function will add a `div` with an `id = "block1"` attribute, with corresponding `width`, `height`, `left`, and `bottom` values (all in percentages). It also returns an object which contains all of the information needed to resize and reposition the `div` that was just created. You can *easily* expand upon this function by adding different classes to each `div`. Anyway, how do we finally make use of our returned object?

```
addGraphic(graphicArr, PercentageBasedGraphic(25, 10, 4, 30, "block1"));
```

The `addGraphic` function adds each new floating box to an array. Later, we iterate through this array upon window resize to reposition all of the floating boxes we defined.

I will be honest with you, the Super Mario graphics made this a lot of fun to work on.

Comment: Pure genius. Thanks so much! Bounty is all yours, as soon as I can award it to you!

Comment: But technically, you could wrap the background image in a div element and pre-define some width for the div. So the `left` and `width` would be calculated based on this container instead of `body`. So then, you would not need to recalculate on resize with JS but let CSS take care of it. Right?

Comment: I tried that first. The problem, as I described, is that the width of the containing element never has to stretch, therefore the `width` and `left` of your blocks are never updated. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KaaXg/1/ ... notice that when you resize the page, `.container` only grows in height and stays the same width. Until you reload the page, your blocks aren't positioned again. Unless someone can come up with a better answer, I can only think of using javascript to complete this task.

Comment: Wow. Now my original answer is completely overdone, but with our collaboration, I think we've come to the easiest method possible... http://jsfiddle.net/KaaXg/3/ You can still use an object factory to create the blocks, if you want, but the solution in this fiddle is probably your best bet. A learning experience for all!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the new fiddle and description of the problem, whether or not you choose to use the object factory is up to you.

Comment: Great, you're the best. One side question, though. I'm trying to limit the `.image` in terms of its `width`. Meaning, if the browser is downsized up to a certain point, it shouldn't resize the background and elements but just show a scrollbar. Any thought about this? I tried adding `min-width` to the background's css, but it gets weird.

Comment: Using a container element makes applying `min-width` and `min-height` much easier. Here are some solutions for both methods: http://jsfiddle.net/HdCEP/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/m2hc3/. Try setting `min-width` and `min-height` to different values to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to check difference between old (before resizing) and new (after) width and height of window and use this difference to change bottom and left position:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var blockLeft = parseInt($('#blockpx').css('left'));
    var blockBottom = parseInt($('#blockpx').css('bottom'));
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var difWidth = width - $(this).width();
        var difHeight = height - $(this).height();
        if (difHeight>0) {
            $('#blockpx').css('bottom',blockBottom-difHeight + 'px');
        } else {
            $('#blockpx').css('bottom',blockBottom+difHeight + 'px');
        }
        if (difWidth>0) {
            $('#blockpx').css('left',blockLeft-difWidth + 'px');
        } else {
            $('#blockpx').css('left',blockLeft+difWidth + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

try on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ77t/15/).

it's a jquery variant, you can do the same using plain javascript.

Comment: Thanks starowere, but this does not seem to work. As you can see, the black block is continuously out of place in comparison to where it should stick..

Comment: it must be the same size all over the time? or it must be resized as window?

Comment: Resized proportionally but scaled as the window is resized.